# Problem with UrlRewritingNet

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a problem with UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter.dll (http://urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html)!

I use html extensions instead aspx like:
`http://myhost.com/defaul.aspx` -> I overwrite to `http://www.myhost.com/defaul.html`, add specific rule to web.config. It works fine on VS2008 developer server, but doesn't on live server.

Is it possible to set some values in `web.config` to inform web-server do not check files ("verify that file exists" checkbox) because I haven't access to IIS because it's hosts by hosting company?

Comment: What version of IIS?  6 or 7?  Also can you explain the h_t_t_p and how that helps anything?

Comment: IIS version 6, (h_t_t_p -> should be http of course, it was to skip spam level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're hosting it in IIS 6, then you need to set up the mapping in IIS. Many shared hosting solutions do not allow this. (Shared hosting is usually the cheapest).

BTW: Its worth noting that the *professional* versions of windows come with IIS, but it's not installed by default. If you can, it's usually best to at least test against a local version of IIS before you start looking at hosting.